# Ajax Multiarray return

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

I try at the moment to get a Multiarray response from a ajax Post json request. 
After hours of trys iam now hope to get help here...

**JS AJAX RESPONSE**

```
 var data = {
  "myid": "1234"
};
 $(".the-return").html("");
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "../post_test/ajax.php", 
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $(".the-return").append("JSON: " + data["messages"]+"<br>");
            });



    alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
  }
})
return false;
```

**PHP**

```
$personen = array( 
    //for each loop from Database 
    array("message","from","to ","datetime"),
    //pushing a Array in a Array ????? 
);
```

*So my Question is now...* 
-> How to return a stable Array to the Ajax Success Function? 
-> And how to read the Return at the Sucess Function so i can Add it  with

```
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
```

I already searched about 40 Sites in Google about Arrays and Ajax Returns but iam not able to figure out the right Way.

My try with

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
```

And on PHP Site

```
    $items .= <<<EOD
                   {
        "s": "0",
        "f": "{$chat['from']}",
        "m": "{$chat['message']}"
   },
```

EOD;

Crashs the Trigger of the Ajax completetly ...

THANKS 
for all Answers

***EDIT***
Its Encoded already in PHP 
-> I need something on JS Side like
   for each message in messages from ajax response 
      message is FROM going TO with TEXT

Comment: Can you explain me this a bit more please ? 
Maybe with a Code Example for understanding? 
Would be awesome

Comment: Just encode it as JSON using the json_encode() function.

Comment: Its already encoded at the PHP Side ...
I forgot to add it here in the code sorry.
I need something like a for each loop 
Like 
for each message in messages

Comment: Like for each message in messages
alert('Got Messages from .... to .... says: asdsd');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of how to do it. File **varex2.php** returns an array of arrays in JSON format. File **varex1.php** decodes the JSON data and displays it in "alert" windows. To test next codes, create two text file, use the given names, copy-paste the codes, open your browser and run `localhost/varex1.php`, here they are:

**varex2.php**

```
<?php

// THIS IS AN ARRAY OF ARRAYS.
$products = Array( Array( "code"  => "0401",
                          "name"  => "shoes",
                          "price" => 700
                        ),
                   Array( "code"  => "0992",
                          "name"  => "shirt",
                          "price" => 250
                        ),
                   Array( "code"  => "5800",
                          "name"  => "glasses",
                          "price" => 400
                        )
                 );
$json = json_encode( $products );
echo $json;  // ARRAY RETURNED IN JSON FORMAT.

?>
```

**varex1.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {
$.ajax( { type : 'POST',
          data : { },
          url  : 'varex2.php',
          success: function ( data ) {
            var i;
            var obj = JSON.parse( data );       // DECODE JSON DATA.
            for ( i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ )  // WALK THE SUB-OBJECTS.
              alert( obj[ i ].code + "\n" +
                     obj[ i ].name + "\n" +
                     obj[ i ].price  );
          },
          error: function ( xhr ) {
            alert( "error" );
          }
        });
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myAjax()">Click here to get the data</button>
  </body>
</html>
```